# Get all the rows from a table who don't have a value in common

Tags: mysql, database, left-join

I have two tables artists and albums.
I want to get all the artists who don't have an album, so I decided to do this but it dosn't
seem to be working:

```
SELECT artists.* FROM albums,artists WHERE COUNT(albums.artist_id)=0;
```

I've also tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM albums,artists WHERE NOT  albums.artist_id=artists.id LIMIT 3;
```

,but it didn't work either.

Here are the artists and albums tables descriptions, respectively.

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL |  |
| name | varchar(50) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| start_year | smallint(6) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| end_year | smallint(6) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| origin | varchar(20) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| type | varchar(10) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| gender | varchar(10) | YES |  | NULL |  |

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL |  |
| name | varchar(100) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| artist_id | int(11) | NO | MUL | NULL |  |
| release_date | date | NO |  | NULL |  |
| release_year | smallint(6) | NO |  | NULL |  |

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where using join syntax from 1989 (with commas) is not serving you well. You need to use an OUTER JOIN, and you can't do that in MySQL with the comma-style join syntax.

```
SELECT artists.* 
FROM artists LEFT OUTER JOIN albums ON albums.artist_id = artists.id
WHERE albums.artist_id IS NULL
```

This is called an *exclusion join*. Being an outer join, it will return all the rows from one joined table (the left table in this case), even if there is no matching row in the other table. In the rows of the result, columns for albums.* will be NULL if there is no match.

Then you just need to use the WHERE clause to select rows where a column from albums that should never be NULL is in fact NULL due to the outer join.

An alternative query that does the same thing:

```
SELECT artists.*
FROM artists
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM albums WHERE artist_id = artists.id)
```

But this is called a *correlated subquery*. It runs the subquery many times, because the result of the subquery depends on the artist id of the outer query.

Using the exclusion join method is usually better for performance, but feel free to test both methods.